# Bundling SCSS for an NPM package release of a React component

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have defined a SASS loader in my webpack config:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
            }, 
           //... other loaders
        ]
}
```

Which allows me to import SASS for my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dashboard.scss';

 export default class Dashboard extends React.Component { ...
```

However, when I am preparing the package for release - I am using BabelJS rather than Webpack as I don't need a bundle but a separate file for each component:

```
babel src --out-dir dist
```

This naturally does not bundle the SCSS as the loader is not called. When I am using the package, I get an error:

```
  Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' 
 ./Dashboard.scss in 
 /Users/Guy/Documents/Guy/jupiterRising/node_modules/project-dashboard/Dashboard
 @ ./~/project-dashboard/Dashboard/Dashboard.js 13:0-27
```

How can I bundle my SCSS properly for an NPM package release without using webpack for bundling?

Comment: did you try extracttextplugin from webpack ? You always can use gulp with browserify and some css extensions

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want. I know that [blueprint](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint) uses webpack to create a NPM package release using webpack.

Comment: Babel does not know what to do with the imported scss files, have you tried using the ignore-styles module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles This will ensure that babel ignores the imported scss files. however - in order to bundle your scss you will probably still have to use webpack